# UIImageView Tap Gesture Sensitivity

Tags: ios5, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an ImageView object on my screen. When I tap it, it displays an info in a bubble style view. The problem is the imageview is very thin and small, it does not pick the tap gesture. Any suggestions about how to increase the sensitivity? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the size of the screen area that is responding to the tap. So you could make the imge view bigger (but set the content mode to center so the image isn't stretched).